# React: Visually reset HTML select tag from onClick in sibling component

Tags: html, reactjs, state

I'm doing a filter for records that conditionally displays one of two options: 1) a list of record.jsx components, or 2) a single noResults.jsx component.

The filter (filter.jsx) is in a component called recordsHeader.jsx as an HTML select tag. It has an onChange event that calls a getRecords method, which allows the resulting records to be filtered according to some options in the select tag.

GOAL: I want to have a button in noResults.jsx that sets the filter back to 'all'. 
Problem: I can pass the getRecords method to it and it will display them but won't visually reset the select tag to 'all'.

I know I can grab the element with jQuery or Vanilla and reset it manually, which works, but I'd like to let React do all the dom stuff for me.

Map of the file structure:

```
- recordsDashboard.jsx
  - savedRecordsView.jsx
    - recordsHeader.jsx
      - filter.jsx
    - noResults.jsx <-- click here and visully reset filter.jsx
    - record.jsx
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code I imagine the savedRecordsView renders something like the following in the case of no results:

```
<RecordsHeader />
<NoResults />
```

That means that savedRecordsView is the shared 'parent' of the two components.  With some rewrite, you could pass a callback via props to NoResults that the button can use to trigger the setting of filter to all.

This callback will update a prop that is passed to RecordsHeader and then to Filter which can re-render the appropriate 'all' setting from what it was originally.

Comment: Nice, yeah this was pretty much it. The problem was basically about figuring out which component should hold the state and what I was having trouble articulating was that HTML elements like the select tag, form, or textfield all have their own state outside of React.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was having trouble articulating this in my question, but HTML elements like select, form, and textfield all have their own state outside of React.

I resolved the issue by moving my handleSelectChange method and filterValue variable from the select component and up into savedRecordsView.jsx so both filter.jsx and noResults.jsx could share them.

This article in the React docs about [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) was pretty much exactly what I was looking for.